# How to read from InputStream?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have an `InputStream` coming from the source and want to read the data using Spark Streaming.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

My very rough understanding of Spark Streaming says to use [ssc.receiverStream](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext) with a custom `Receiver`.

Consult [Spark Streaming Custom Receivers](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Spark Streaming API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext) provides various methods for reading data from different sources - As of Spark 1.5.2 it provides utility functions to read streaming data from: -

1. Binary or Text Files or Directories
2. Raw Sockets
3. Queues

For any other data source you need to provide the custom implementation of Streaming Receivers and further leverage following method of *StreamingContext*

> StreamingContext.receiverStream[T](receiver: Receiver[T])

Details about implementing custom Streaming receivers can be found [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html).